# How to link library into shared object with G++/LD

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries

I am working on a C++ project which will be compiled to a shared object file. It needs to have access to the python interpreter, which is where I reach my hurdle: upon linking, I receive `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol '__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object`
(The opening quotation on `__TMC_END__` was a backtick, but this ruined the formatting so I changed it, if this is useful information).

The obvious solution is to download the Python source and compile it along with my code, but I would rather not complicate my development workflow to this point, thus, my question is: how do I embed the Python interpreter in my shared object file?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with a full Python 3.9 install, and access to all development files.

(My apologies if this is the wrong site)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my problem was solved by adding the python lib to the g++ shared-object-builder command. I previously only added it to the first phase of compilation (convert into an object file).